# Illuminate\Session\SessionInterface not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to run Laravel 4 application in Google App engine. I am following this [tutorial](http://blog.neoxia.com/laravel-4-on-google-appengine-for-php/) but the problem is that when I run it by using cmd

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine>python dev_appserver.py --skip_sdk_update_check=yes --port=8080
--admin_port=8000 --php_executable_path=C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php-cgi.exe  C:\laravel-test\laravel
```

it shows the following error:

```
Fatal error: Interface 'Illuminate\Session\SessionInterface' not found in C:\laravel-test\laravel\bootstrap\compiled.php on line 7301
```

compiled.php:  http://laravel.io/bin/ekP5m

Answer (score 2):

I Also got this error during update using composer.In the composer.json file. there should not include two require parts

ex :  --- this is not working 
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
    "neoxia/laravel-openssl-encryption": "1.0.*"
},
"require": {
      "evernote/evernote": "dev-master"
},

this will work 
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
    "neoxia/laravel-openssl-encryption": "1.0.*",
    "evernote/evernote": "dev-master"
},

please check your file and make sure about that i think this will work